flutter state is not updating after logout showing old users data
I'm using provider using mvvm. I'm fetching api, but the response it not changing after new users login its showing old users data. I have deleted all data from local storage and local storage data is showing properly, but the get api data after login changing it shows the old users data.
Future<bool> logout(BuildContext context) async {
  _logout = DataState.loading("");
  notifyListeners();
  try {
    final result = await authRepository.logout();
    _logout = DataState.completed(result);
    isLoggedIn = false;
    _user = null;
    _logout = DataState.completed(true);
  } catch (error, stackTrace) {
    isLoggedIn = false;
    _logout = DataState.error(error.toString());
    Utils.instance.logError(error, stackTrace);
  }
  notifyListeners();
  return _logout.data ?? false;
}

and I'm showing main dart changenotifier code also here
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  MaterialTheme theme = getTheme(context);
  final localViewModel = Provider.of<LocaleViewModel>(
    context,
  );
  debugPaintSizeEnabled = false;
  return MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider<AuthViewModel>(
        create: (_) => _authViewModel,
      ),
      ChangeNotifierProvider<IntroViewModel>(
        create: (_) => _introViewModel,
      ),
      ChangeNotifierProvider<RegisterViewModel>(
        create: (_) => _registerViewModel,
      ),
      ChangeNotifierProvider<SettingsViewModel>(
        create: (_) => _settingViewModel,
      ),
      ChangeNotifierProvider<SearchViewModel>(
        create: (_) => _searchViewModel,
      ),
      ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (_) => PlansViewModel(_plansListRepository),
      ),
      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ChatViewModel()),
      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ProfileViewModel()),
      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => NotificationsViewModel()),
      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => DashBoardViewModel()),
      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => CommonShimmerViewModel()),
      ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (_) => BlockViewModel(),
      ),
      ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (_) => BranchViewModel(),
      ),
      ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (_) => ContactUsViewModel(),
      )
    ],
    child: Consumer<SettingsViewModel>(
        builder: (settingContext, setting, child) {
      return ScreenUtilInit(
          designSize: const Size(390, 720),
          child: MaterialApp.router(
              themeMode: setting.themeMode,
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              theme: theme.light().copyWith(splashColor: Colors.blueGrey),
              // darkTheme: theme
              //     .darkMediumContrast()
              //     .copyWith(splashColor: Colors.blueGrey),
              localizationsDelegates: AppLocalizations.localizationsDelegates,
              supportedLocales: AppLocalizations.supportedLocales,
              locale: localViewModel.locale,
              builder: (context, child) {
                if (child == null) {
                  throw ('No child in .router constructor builder');
                }
                return AuthScope(
                  notifier: _authViewModel,
                  child: child,
                );
              },
              routerConfig: router));
    }),
  );
}

